# Add Under Review Administrator Tag

Tags: discussion, tags, meta

User Voice provided a mechanism wherein suggestions that the dev team was discussing were marked as "under review." Would a similar Administrator Tag (the ones in red) be of use as a means of indicating that suggestions here on meta hadn't been lost in the flood?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, we already have this:

[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

Comment: 18 seconds faster.

Comment: *and* I've made my link into a pretty button ;-)

Comment: I like pretty button.

Comment: Also status-deferred is a close synonym.

Comment: It would have helped to search by "review" and not just "under" *blush*

Comment: @Ian: `status-deferred` is close, but it means "we'll look at it later" and not "we're looking into it"

Comment: Yeah I know, but it means that they *will* look into it! Thats why I said *close*

Comment: @Ian: Sure. I just wanted to clarify why the two aren't interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

That tag already exists.

[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)